# Black and White Manga about a male mc crafting super pure iron ingot out of red sand

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

In a certain isekai world series name I wish to find, there is this child, our main character has just returned with his group from a mining deposit. The mining deposit has been exhausted of iron ores, but red iron sand still exists. Our main character thus said to his group that he knows there is some more iron inside said sand and crafted a near 100% purity iron ingot to them using alchemy. It turns out alchemy is rumored to be a scam in the isekai world, and the mc just disapproved it. They try to sell it to some merchant, but the merchant can’t believe what he had seen. I do remember he didn’t purchase the high purity ingot tho, but our mc made another common iron ingot, by adding impurities to his shiny iron ingot, and passed it again to the merchant.

Comment: "Possibly the Greatest Alchemist of All Time" has a mining scene, but it appears to be regular mining, not alchemic. "The Reincarnated Prince Becomes an Alchemist and Brings Prosperity to His Country" has alchemy be forbidden/lost knowledge, but I don't see a mining scene in the chapters I skimmed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer on reddit.

It's *[**By The Grace of the Gods**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/By_the_Grace_of_the_Gods)* (*Kami-tachi ni Hirowareta Otoko*)

> Ryoma Takebayashi is a lonely man who led a life filled with hardships until he dies from an unfortunate accident during his sleep. In the afterlife, he is greeted by three gods who grew fond of him and send him to another world as a child, where he makes use of his innate knowledge and abilities, combined with the gods' blessings, to live a new life filled with challenges and happy meetings.
>
> [image]